# Prefill Input/Form on external website

Tags: javascript, forms, http

I am trying to find a way to prefill an external HTML form/Input with data possibly using Javascript? I do not own the website that the form is on, so that makes things difficult. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This is vague. Do you intend to load the external website in your own web page as an `<iframe>`? Otherwise, there is not way you can manipulate DOM on any arbitrary client.

Comment: I do not have an issue with using an iframe

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

Now, this is almost surely not going to help you. But, for the sake of completeness: there is *one* way to communicate with an iframe, even if it is cross-origing: the `postMessage` API.

The way it works is simple. On your website you do:

```
let win = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow;
win.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ key: value }));
```

And the iframe has to be listening for the `postMessage`, like this:

```
document.addEventListener("message", function(e){
        console.log("Domain:", e.domain, "sent", e.data);
});
```

Of course you'd have to contact the `iframe` developer and arrange for them to listen to your post, and furthermore to pre-fill the form with whatever you send as `data`. In many scenarios, this is unrealistic. But it is possible.

---

Accessing any element of an iframe that does not reside in the same domain, is the [definition of cross-side(-frame) scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Frame_Scripting).

However, if you were to get the page on the same domain it would be easy to prefill the form.

A parent frame can have access to an `<iframe>` elements using the DOM API. Let's set up our constants:

```
const iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
const innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

You have to have knowledge of the structure of the page that your are embedding. Assuming you do, with `innerDoc` you can access the fields that need to be pre-filled.

Let's take an example. Say that the form in the `<iframe>` looks like this

```
<form>
  <label>Some field 
    <input name="an-input" type="text"/>
  </label>
</form>
```

To fill the `input` element we simply do

```
const input = innerDoc.querySelector("[name='an-input']");
input.value = "Filler text";
```

Comment: This will only be used internally inside our company. We are currently entering vin numbers manually several times per day, it would be much easier to be able to click a link on our website and have it prepopulate the link on autozones website. Is there any way around this?

Comment: "Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin"

Comment: See the first line of the post. You're going to get that because you're not allowed to manipulate the DOM (the internals) of a site that is not part of your domain. This is a security feature of all modern broswers, and there's really nothing you can do to get around it :(

Comment: is there a browser we could use internally OR a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I’ve been able to manipulate sites I don’t control is with a bookmarklet.  An extension can be used too but a bookmarklet is easier and has no restrictions.

…now if I could just do this on mobile somehow.